# Memory issues in R when running models in caret

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I am new to R and trying to generate predictions of a "yes"/"no" variable using an ensemble model. To do so, I am using `caret` to generate predictions using a random forest (`ranger`), a LASSO (`glmnet`) and a gradient boosted regression tree (`xgblinear`) model. My dataset contains around 600k observations and 500 variables (a mix of continuous and binary variables, weighting 322MB), of which I am using 30% to train the models.

Here is the code I am using for this:

```
train_control_final <- trainControl(method = "none", savePredictions = TRUE, allowParallel = T, classProbs = TRUE,summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

rff_final <- train(training_y~., data = training_final, method = "ranger", 
                       tuneGrid = rfgrid_final, num.trees = 250, metric = "ROC", sample.fraction = 0.1,
                       replace = TRUE, trControl=train_control_final, maximize = FALSE, na.action = na.omit)

rboost_final <- train(training_y~., data = training_final, method = "xgbLinear", 
                          tuneGrid = boostgrid_final, metric = "ROC", subsample = 0.1,
                          trControl=train_control_final, maximize = FALSE, na.action = na.omit)

rlasso_final <- train(training_y~., data = training_final, method = "glmnet", 
                          tuneGrid = lassogrid_final, metric = "ROC",
                          trControl=train_control_final, maximize = FALSE, na.action = na.omit)
```

In a first step, I use a different 10% of the sample to tune the parameters for each model (using 3-fold CV), with the results stored in rf/lasso/boostgrid_final (for this, I use the same code structure).

The problem is that every time I run this code to generate the predictions, R crashes because of memory issues. The code works without problems when tuning the parameters and when including less variables (around 60). So my question is what can I try to make this work with the full dataset? Or is there an alternative way of accomplish what I want (generate predictions using these three different algorithms) without running into memory issues?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Besides the question but why would you like to minimize ROC? And method = "none" in train control does not lead to any tuning. I think you should first read in detail the help of the functions you are using.

Comment: The tuning is not done in this part of the code, it's done before using a similar code structure. In that case I have adjusted trainControl to perform 3-fold CV, and then the tuned parameters are the ones store in rf/lasso/boostgrid_final.